# Loading File in External Tomcat Container vs Bootrun

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot, rule-engine

I am trying to load a file in Spring.
The file contains Rules based on OpenRules engine.
The problem is when I am using Spring BootRun it is loaded properly.
But when I am trying to deploy the same file in External Tomcat I am getting error FileNotFound.

I am mentioning the file path in property file in the following way:

```
rules.open.main.decision.path=file:rules/main/Decision.xls
```

The rules folder is directly under the Project Folder.

In Java I am loading the file:

```
public Decision getDecisionEngine(){        
    String decisionName = "CustomerPreventStrategies";
    //String fileName = "file:rules/main/Decision.xls";
    String fileName = env.getProperty("rules.open.main.decision.path");
    System.out.println("rules.open.main.decision.path:"+fileName);

    Decision decision = new Decision(decisionName,fileName);
    return decision;    
}
```

When I am creating the WAR for external Tomcat I am keeping it in 2 locations. But it is not helping.

```
 war {
    baseName = 'MyOpenRules'
    version =  '0.1.0'
    from("rules") {
        into("WEB-INF/classes/rules")
        }
    from("rules") {
        into("rules")
        }    
}
```

I am getting:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: rules\main\Decision.xls (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Comment: After trial and error I found for external Tomact if I keep the **rules** folder under **tomcat** **bin** it is working fine. But was unable to decipher why.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
rules.open.main.decision.path=file:/rules/main/Decision.xls
```

This makes the Springs to pick from location WEB-INF/classes/rules/main/Decision.xml

When you use 
    rules.open.main.decision.path=file:rules/main/Decision.xls
the file is expected to be in the current directory. When us start tomcat server through catalina.bat or startup.bat which is inside Tomcat_HOME/bin then bin directory is the current folder for that process. Hence when u kept the file inside tomcat bin that worked.

When u put / spring uses relative path to look for file.

Comment: Thanks. Now I completely understand how "current directory" influencing the behavior for external tomcat. But putting "/" in front did not resolve the issue. I used  `../webapps/${name}/rules/`  to resolve.